# Python specify config file from command line

Tags: python, command-line, command, config

I have created a python program that I will be compiling into an EXE but before that I want to have a command line switch that lets me specify the config file I want to use.  My idea is to have multiple config files that server different purposes.  I have searched the internet but am confused by what I am seeing.  Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Why not just use a command line parameter for the config file?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) module, which handles command line options for you.

Edit: Let me give you a simple example.

```
import argparse

# create a new argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple argument parser")
# add a new command line option, call it '-c' and set its destination to 'config'
parser.add_argument("-c", action="store", dest="config_file")

# get the result
result = parser.parse_args()
# since we set 'config_file' as destination for the argument -c, 
# we can fetch its value like this (and print it, for example):
print(result.config_file)
```

You can then proceed to use `result.config_file` as the file name of the config file passed to the script.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at that but I am a huge newbie at this and I am a little confused by what I am seeing... If you could provide any additional insight it would be greatly appreciated... I will continue to try to figure it out...

Comment: So if I understand what I am seeing I can
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", dest="config")
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open(config))

Comment: user3739525: Try it and see.